# Adding a Swipe view to Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: java, android, user-interface

So like i got a Navigation Drawer that is implemented, content page is empty, i want to make the page scroll-able so that a user will see three different pages when swiping left or right, is it possible to do this? i have been researching but i havent found any help so far

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your code with us, preferable as it is described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Share your code whatever you have tried or share snapshot what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes it is very much possible. Have a look at FragmentPagerAdapter to enable swiping fragments in the container of the navigation drawer.

Comment: Thing is i haven't attempted to do it, Currently researching and attempting it

Answer (score 1):

Actually this Example Helped me, thanks for the info guys
https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout